# How can I check who is running my DNS?

Tags: ssl, dns, cloudflare

I set up cloudflare with ssl and a 301 redirect to ssl this morning. Everything seemed to work, but now, i'm back on http and the redirect is not working. I'm trying to figure out why and the DNS-system is sometimes a bit hard to decipher. I'm using a swedish registrar, Loopia. Loopia in turn passes the DNS-records to cloudflare.

Is there some way to figure out if I even go through cloudflare any more?

Comment: From a linux machine `host www.yourdomain.com` should return the IP's - check and see if they are your or Cloudflares as a first start.

Answer (score 0):

To determine which names servers you have set:
    dig NS DOMAIN

This should only return Cloudflare name servers (unless you enabled Cloudflare via your hosting provider's integration). If you see other name servers in addition to the Cloudflare name servers that indicates you left your other names servers in place at the time you setup Cloudflare. To use Cloudflare you'd need to remove all other name servers other than the ones they provide. Other name servers being in place would return non-Cloudflare IPs which would explain the behavior you're seeing.